# angularjs textarea model with \n should start new line

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I have sample json as shown below and I am trying to represent key in label and value in textarea ([Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GkeFguhgAg1ymWQCjfc6?p=preview)). But the textarea is not working if the model contains "\n". Whenever there is a \n I would like the text to appear in new line.

```
 $scope.sampleData =  {
    "id": 10000,
    "transactionid": "gec43434",
    "status": "COMPLETED",
    "session_id": "TTYUU455667",
    "errors": "1",
    "start_timestamp": "2016-11-07 02:35:35",
    "log_field": "\n\nSample Text\nRowX\n\nRowY\nRowZ\n"
  }
```

In textarea, I want "log_field" value to be appeared as :

```
Sample Text
RowX
RowY
RowZ
```

Even if there are multiple \n\n... there should be only one line break.

Comment: Textarea seems to be working, you need to scroll down in the textarea to see the value in the "log_field", since it starts with 2 \n's.

Answer (score 0):

Textarea seems to be working, did you scroll down in the `log_field` textarea, since it starts with 2 \n's?

As for your last query, you should create a custom filter, which can replace multiple continuous newlines with a single newline character. It's pretty easy and basic, but do let me know if you need more direction.

More info about filters here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter. It also gives an example on how to create a custom filter.

Comment: Yes you are right. Do you have any solution for my last query

Comment: @MadasuK You can write an angular custom filter for that and use it directly in the HTML, wherever you want. Basically they're used to format data for display. More info here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Answer (score -1):

You could use the following to remove the extra new line characters:

```
"\n\nSample Text\nRowX\n\nRowY\nRowZ\n".replace(/\n\s*\n/g, '\n');
```

```js
var text = "\n\nSample Text\nRowX\n\nRowY\nRowZ\n".replace(/\n\s*\n/g, '\n');
document.getElementById("foo").value = text;
```

```html
<textarea id="foo"></textarea>
```

Comment: @VatsalJuneja of course it would. I just show how can OP use it. Apparently the sample data he OP defined has a format close to that will take from an API. After consuming the API, he can process the data, before would define it's model.

Comment: First, OP is not using any ID's. Even if we choose to ignore that for now, your solution will also change the value in the sampleData, due to two-way data binding of angularjs, which might not be required. Let's even choose to ignore this for now, your solution is not DRY; this can be very easily done via filters, writing code for which is even simpler than what OP has shown in the plunker.

Comment: @VatsalJuneja Of course he doesn't use any ID's. I just throw a snippet, in order to show that replace with the pattern we pass works as it is expected. Regarding the two way binding, the replace would be applied only once on the load of data. Please note that I mention that the data would be post-processed. I don't claim that when a user writes into the textarea should be applied the relpace. If this is not clear, please let me know, in order to make it more clear. I hope that I answered both your questions.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the following code:

```
$scope.sampleData.log_field = $scope.sampleData.log_field.replace(/\\n{1,}/g,'\\n');
```